# What is the default path of newly created tar archive?

Tags: linux, tar

I created `tar` archive using following command:

```
tar -zcvf archive-name.tar.gz directory-name
```

After this operation, where that tar.gz is located?

Comment: in the directory form which you are running the command - this is standard almost all programs. Use `pwd` to know where you are

Comment: I searched there but I can't find that file.

Comment: type `ls -ltr` to see the latest files on the current directory.

Comment: @Fiximan programs don't even have to do anything. `tar` (and any other application) receives a valid path that is used directly as a filename. In this case, it is a relative path of the simplest form: no subdirectory, no `../` or anything like that, just a file in the current working directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is created in place where you executed the script. You can see your current location using `pwd`.

However, you can also pass path instead of archive-name:

```
tar -zcvf /my/absolute/path/archive-name.tar.gz directory-name
```

File will be located in /my/absolute/path.

You can also use relative path, if the directory is there:

```
tar -zcvf relative/path/to/pwd/archive-name.tar.gz directory-name
```

Answer (score 2):

The tar-file should be located in the very directory from which you ran the command.

To find out where you are, type `pwd -P`. See [this article](https://superuser.com/questions/300044/which-command-in-the-linux-unix-sh-shell-returns-my-current-directory) for an explanation why to use the `-P`.